# Residue of $e^{1/z(z-1)}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How can I calculate the residue of $f(z) = e^{\frac{1}{z(z-1)}}$ at $z=0$?

I can't just expand it formally in powers of $z$ like this
$$
e^{1/z(z-1)} = e^{1/z + 1 + z + \ldots} = 1 + \left(\frac1z + 1 + z + \ldots\right) + \frac12 \left( \frac1z + 1 + z + \ldots \right)^2 + \ldots
$$
and calculate the sum of the series of coefficients before $z^{-1}$ (or can I?). Even if it's valid it's not so easy.

Also I thought about that finding that residue is about finding the integral of $f$ over the circle around $0$ with radius less than $1$: $\int_{R=\frac12} f(z) dz$. If I'd make a change of a variable $z = \frac1w$ it would become $\int_{R=2} \frac{1}{w^2} e^{\frac{w^2}{1-w^2}} dw$. The integrand is holomorphic in $\{z \in \mathbb C : |z| > 1\}$ so we just need to calculate the residue at $\infty$. But that looks too complex too.

Comment: Don't use partial fractions.  Just expand directly with the power series for $e^x$.

Comment: @Stella, yeah there would be some binomial coefficients, but is seems I don't have enough experience in combinatorics to do that. $e^{-\sum_{i=-1}^\infty} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} (-1)^k \left( \sum_{i=-1}^\infty z^i \right)^k$. And I'm stuck even in finding the coefficient before $z^{-1}$ in $\left( \sum_{i=-1}^\infty z^i \right)^k$. It's the same as the coefficient before $z^{k-1}$ in $\left( \sum_{i=0}^\infty z^i \right)^k$ or in $\left( \sum_{i=-1}^{k-1} z^i \right)^k$. It would be some nasty sum of multinomial coefficients which I have no idea what to do with.

Comment: @Paul, you mean $e^{1/z(z-1)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \frac{1}{z^k} \frac{1}{(z-1)^k}$? OK, I can find that $\frac{1}{(z-1)^k} = \frac{(-1)^k}{(k-1)!} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+k-1)!}{n!} z^n$. So the coefficient before $z^{-1}$ would be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2 (n+1)!}$. I have no idea what to do with that monster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can rewrite $$\frac{1}{z(z-1)} = \frac{z-1}{z} + \frac{z}{z-1} - 2.$$ The modified Bessel functions of the first kind are defined by $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} I_n(z) w^n = e^{(zw + zw^{-1})/2}.$$ In particular, $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} I_n(2) w^n = e^{ w + w^{-1}}.$$ Setting $w = \frac{z-1}{z}$, we get $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} I_n(2) \frac{(z-1)^n}{z^n} = e^{\frac{1}{z(z-1)} + 2}.$$ In particular, since the residue of $(1 - 1/z)^n$ at $z=0$ is $-n$ for $n \ge 0$ (and $0$ otherwise), the residue of $e^{\frac{1}{z(z-1)}}$ is $$e^{-2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} I_n(2) \cdot (-n) = e^{-2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Big( I_{n+1}(2) - I_{n-1}(2) \Big),$$ which telescopes to $-e^{-2}(I_{-1}(2) + I_0(2)) \approx -0.528.$ This is numerically correct as WolframAlpha integrates

> e^(1 / (e^(2iz)/4 - e^(iz)/2)) * e^(iz)/2 dz for z=0 to 2*pi

to something very close to $2\pi$ times $-0.528$.