# Residue of $e^{\frac{z-2}{z(z-1)}}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series, singularity

> What is the residue of $f(z)=e^{\frac{z-2}{z(z-1)}}$ at $z=0$?

I was trying to compute it using tricks shown here: [Residue of $e^{1/z(z-1)}$ at $z=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266511/residue-of-e1-zz-1-at-z-0)

I wrote 
$$\frac{z-2}{z(z-1)}=\frac1z-\frac{1}{z(z-1)}=\frac1z+2-\frac{z-1}{z}-\frac{z}{z-1}.$$
Thus we can write
$$f(z)=e^{1/z+2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} I_n(-2)(1-\tfrac{1}{z})^n,$$
where $I_n(x)$ are the modified Bessel functions of the first kind. However, writing $e^{1/z}$ as a series, we see that $I_n(-2)$ for negative $n$ can contribute towards the residue. So not sure if this helps.

Any help/suggestions are welcome.